# How is the defprotocol macro defined in clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to figure out where is the source code the `defprotocol` macro is defined.

in the `cljs.core` source:

https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs

The `defprotocol` macros pops up suddenly on line 155 (along with the `-invoke` function). Where can we find where it is implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All macros in ClojureScript have to be implemented as Clojure.

The `defprotocol` is implemented at line 796 of this file:

https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/clj/cljs/core.clj#L796

Note that this file is a Clojure file, not a ClojureScript file.

Comment: Thanks! Btw... Do you know how the js* macro works? I see it all over the cljs.core code but there is no definition

Comment: js* is not a macro it's a special form. It's used to allow ClojureScript to drop to Javascript when needed. In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5edtbpVOOBI&feature=player_detailpage#t=1681s) Chris Houser talks a little bit about it.

Comment: The code that implements js* is in this file: [analyzer.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/clj/cljs/analyzer.clj#L826)

Comment: Hello, I write a post to explain how clojurescript compile defprotocol in javascript, this maybe can help you :)
http://blog.klipse.tech//clojurescript/2016/04/09/clojurescript-protocols-secret.html